# Are Sobolev isometries in Minkowski space smooth

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, regularity, isometric-immersion, minkowski-space

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be an open regular domain and let $f\in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^d)$ satisfy that $df\in\operatorname{SO}(d)$ almost-everywhere. It was proved by Reshetnyak (in a wider Riemannian context) that $f$ is in fact smooth, hence an affine Euclidean isometry.

Question: Does a similar assertion in Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}^{1,d}$? The Euclidean proof relies on ellipticity, hence doesn't seem generalizable.

Comment: Can you provide a citation for Reshetnyak's result? (I am having difficulty seeing how ellipticity is involved.)

Comment: @WillieWong, here is one paper about this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.08892.pdf

Comment: @WillieWong Just as a sketch of the proof, for every Sobolev map between manifolds of equal dimensions, div(cof df))=0 (with the appropriate interpretation)). If df is in SO(), then cof(df) = df, i.e., the map is (weakly) harmonic, hence smooth. (The complete proof involves more technical details, but that's the gist of it.)

Comment: Thanks @DeaneYang and Raz.

Comment: Quick followup: why the specification of $SO$? If $df \in O(d)$, then you still have $\mathrm{cof}(df) = \pm df$ and still get weakly harmonic. But it seems to me that orientation preserving may be important: how to see that in the sketch?

Comment: @WillieWong If the map is everywhere orientation preserving, then no problem. But if you allow the map to change orientation then the projection on O(d) is no longer a Sobolev map